Draw a path line for indoor map Mapbox
Is there any way to find a path in indoor map, ex using A* algorithm i struggling because A* algorithm works based on grid but I have a geojson of indoor map is there any way to do
thanks for your help
i haved tried it using a* algorithm but I have problem on getting grid of mapbox geojson
